# Read a netcdf file with multiprocessing

Tags: multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, netcdf4

I have a netcdf file as in the below. I made a test to read it with the multiprocessing (so that the reading may be faster).

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import multiprocessing

fname = 'testfile.nc'
nc = Dataset(fname, 'w', format='NETCDF4')
data1 = np.random.randn(100, 100, 100)
data2 = np.random.randn(100, 100, 100)
nc.createDimension('x', 100)
nc.createDimension('y', 100)

var1 = nc.createVariable('grid1', np.float, ('x', 'y', 'z'))
var2 = nc.createVariable('grid2', np.float, ('x', 'y', 'z'))

var1[:] = data1
var2[:] = data2

nc.close()

def readnc(fname):
    dataset = Dataset(fname, 'r')
    return dataset['grid1'][:]  


pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2)
a=pool.map(readnc,fname)
pool.close()
```

But there is an IOERROR:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'm'
```

The versions of netcdf and netcdf4-python are: netCDF 4.6.1, netcdf4-Python 1.4.1. I do not understand very well this problem. If someone could explain to me, it would be great ! Thanks in advance !

Best regards,

Xiaoni

Answer (score 0):

I made some correction in your code, so it should work now. Nevertheless, I am not sure that you can speed up the reading of the netCDF with a code like this...

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
import time

fname = 'testfile.nc'
nc = Dataset(fname, 'w', format='NETCDF4')
data1 = np.random.randn(100, 100, 100)
data2 = np.random.randn(100, 100, 100)
nc.createDimension('x', 100)
nc.createDimension('y', 100)
nc.createDimension('z', 100)
var1 = nc.createVariable('grid1', np.float, ('x', 'y', 'z'))
var2 = nc.createVariable('grid2', np.float, ('x', 'y', 'z'))

var1[:] = data1
var2[:] = data2

nc.close()
# -------------------------------------
def readnc(fname):
    #print fname
    dataset = Dataset(fname, 'r')
    return dataset['grid1'][:]  
# -------------------------------------
for itest in range(10):
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    tic=time.time();
    a=pool.map(readnc,(fname,))
    print 'Multiprocessing: ',time.time()-tic,'seconds'
    pool.close();
# --------------------------------------
for itest in range(10):
    tic=time.time();
    a=readnc(fname)
    print 'Serial: ',time.time()-tic,'seconds'
```

The part with multiprocessing is taking ~0.04 seconds to run, whereas the serial part takes less than 0.01 seconds. I have a feeling that the multiprocessing part makes 4 processes with the same task - reading in the whole dataset instead of reading in only parts of it and giving one whole output with the data.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. I also realized that this is not the right way to speed up the computation. Finally, I used the Serial reading with some preprocessing applied to my netcdf data. It works faster for my problem.